# Parsing a URL in Java

Tags: java, php

I am looking for an equivalent to PHP's "parse_url" function in Java. I am *not* running in Tomcat.  I have query strings saved in a database that I'm trying to break apart into individual parameters.  I'm working inside of Pentaho, so I only have the Java SE classes to work with.  I know I could write a plugin or something, but if I'm going to do all that I'll just write the script in PHP and be done with it.

TLDR:  Looking for a Java standard class/function that takes a String and spits out an array of parameters.

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish that using [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html):

```
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:port/path?arg=value#anchor");
String protocol = url.getProtocol(); // http
String host = url.getHost(); // hostname
String path = url.getPath(); // /path
int port = url.getPort(); // port
String query = url.getQuery(); // arg=value
String ref = url.getRef(); // anchor
```

Comment: Also you may need `getUserInfo()`.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The OP has "query strings" saved in a database that he wants turned into a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Here's something quick and dirty (have not compiled it, but you should get the idea.

```
URL url = new URL("http://...");
String query = url.getQuery();
String paramStrings[] = query.split("\\&");
HashMultiMap<String, String> params = HashMultiMap.create(); // <== google guava class
for (int i=0;iparamStrings.length;i++) {
    String parts[] = params[i].split("=");
    params.put(URLDecoder.decode(parts[0], "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(parts[1], "UTF-8"));
}

Set<String> paramVals = params.get("paramName");
```

If you don't want to use the guava class, you can accomplish the same thing with some additional code, and a HashMap>

Answer (score -2):

No such thing in Java. You will need to parse the strings manually and create your own array.  You could create your own parse_url using StringTokenizer, String.split, or Regular Expressions rather easily.

You could also cast those strings from the database back to URL objects and parse them that way, [here are the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html).

Answer (score -4):

String has a split function, but you will need to write your own regex to determine how to split the string.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: I've seen plenty of code examples to break a QS apart by hand.  I was figuring since Java was one of the first languages to spring on the internet that it would have some kind of "built in" way for parsing the QS into a HashMap or the like.