# Prevent regex from matching slash characters

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex `\/\/.*\/.*?` and I am applying it to strings in this format: `mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs`

Based on the above the returned match is: `//localhost:27017/` however, I do not want the `//../` characters I only want the result to be: `localhost:27017`

What needs to be modified in order to achieve this, I am fairly new to regex building.

Edit: I am using Java 1.7 to execute this regex statement.

Comment: Can you use lookbehinds? `(?<=\/\/)[^\/]*`.

Comment: What language are you using?  You might be better off using existing code that extracts the hostname and port number from URLs rather than messing with a regex to do it.

Comment: I am using Java 1.7, any recommendations?

Comment: I don't know about Java, but there has to be a URL parsing function somewhere, I would think.  I know that in PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408498/parsing-a-url-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `replaceAll` approach in Java if you do not want to use `Matcher`:

```
System.out.println("mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs".replaceAll("mongodb://([^/]*).*", "$1"));
```

Here, I assume you have 1 occurrence of a mongodb URL. `mongodb://` matches the sequence of characters  literally, the `([^/]*)` matches a sequence of 0 or more characters other than `/` and stores them in a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 (we'll use the backreference `$1` to this group to retrieve the text in the replacement pattern). `.*` matches all symbols up to the end of a one-line string.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3AvZSm)

Or, with `Matcher`,

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<=//)[^/]*");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The regex here - `(?<=//)[^/]*` - matches again a sequence of 0 or more characters other than `/` (with `[^/]*`), but makes sure there is `//` *right before* this sequence. `(?<=//)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that does not consume characters, and thus does not return them in the match.

Comment: Thanks, could explain what it actually does?

Comment: I added explanations and some links. Please let me know if there is anything unclear about this. Lots of people don't like `Matcher` since it requires adding another `import`, and more code, but it helps you retrieve matches or capturing groups individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of lookbehinds and lookaheads to replace all the "/" like:
    `(?<=\/\/).+.*(?=\/).*?`

Will match only localhost:27017 from your query

Here the `(?<=\/\/).` is matching to anything after the "//" string
and the `(?=\/)` is matching anything before the "/" string